# Is possible to change the Javascript in the clients browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

on a webform I'm using JQuery Validator to check my form data, however I don't add any validation on the server side.
I would like to know if is possible for a user to alter the code and remove my validations from their browser. If that is possible, how could I prevent it?

Comment: solution: validate on the server as well - the way I look at it is. Client side validation is to avoid sending needless invalid requests. Server side validation to prevent malicious requests (like you describe) - so, you really should validate at both ends of the request

Comment: Never. Trust. The. Client.

Comment: Say it with me now...

Comment: Yes. They can use Postman. Postman is easy to use and a lot of people know it exists. More clever people even know that you can open the developer tools, switch to network tab, right-click and copy as curl, open Postman, click the "import" button and paste the curl code to make a modified request

Comment: Nobody needs a browser, and even less your js code, to make HTTP requests to your server. Always do validation on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code on the browser can be tempered maliciously, you must always include validations on your server/backend/api